# How to get value of an XML node?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

For the life of me I have not been able to extract the `SourcePartyName` from this XML document:

```
<ns0:Visit xmlns:ns0="http://Co.Burgers.Ues">
<ns0:SourcePartyName>NDHARY</ns0:SourcePartyName>
</ns0:Visit>
```

Using Scott's [solution](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GetNamespacesFromAnXMLDocumentWithXPathDocumentAndLINQToXML.aspx), I've been able to extract the namespace info; however, after dozens of attempts at monkeying with `XDocument` / `XElement`, I have not been able to get the desired `NDHARY` value.

Attempts have included:

`xdoc.Descendants(ns + "SourcePartyName").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;`

and

`xdoc.Element(ns + "SourcePartyName").Value;`

**How do you get the value of a node from an XDocument?**

Comment: Try following : xdoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "SourcePartyName").Select(x => (string)x).FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an `XDocument` you have to go via its **`Root`** property.

```
String xml = @"
    <ns0:Visit xmlns:ns0=""http://Co.Burgers.Ues"">
        <ns0:SourcePartyName>NDHARY</ns0:SourcePartyName>
    </ns0:Visit>
    ";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = "http://Co.Burgers.Ues";
String sourcePartyName = (String)xdoc.Root.Element(ns + "SourcePartyName");
```